# Usage of ようにだそうだ

Tags: colloquial-language

I saw this sentence reading some manga:

```
自分たちで処分するようにだそうだ
```

I think in this context it means "I heard you guys are taking care of it yourselves".

However I am surprised by the way だ follows after ように. Is this just a colloquial equivalent to:

```
自分たちで処分するようにしそうだ
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 自分たちで処分するようにだそうだ。

≒

> 『自分たちで処分するように！』だそうだ。

「～～ように」 is a little curt-sounding imperative-sentence-ender.  (Teachers often use it with students in schools.)

「～～だそうだ」＝「～～ということだ」＝「～～という[話]{はなし}だ」  These phrases are used to ***quote hearsay statements***.

So, Person A said 『自分たちで処分するように！』 to Person B and the speaker has heard it from Person B (or yet another person who heard it from Person B).

= ***"I hear (or 'It seems') that (Person A) has said that we should handle it by ourselves."***

Your sentence 「自分たちで処分するようにしそうだ。」 does not make any sense, I am afraid to say.

Answer (score 1):

I guess quotation marks are missing:

> 「自分たちで処分するように」だそうだ
>   I hear “Take care of it yourselves.”